# How to implement spring boot pessimistic lock and which approach is better optimistic lock or pessimistic lock?

Tags: spring-boot, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

1. Setup version on entity class

   @Column(name = "VERSION")
     @Version
     private int version;

   }
2. `entityManager.find(getActiveUsers.class, 1, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);`

Comment: optimistic locking is most preferable as long as it doesn't acquire any locks on your table

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve optimistic lock using @version on my entity class. which approach is better?